# Extract value from html tag by Regular Expression Extractor of JMeter

Tags: html, jmeter

I have a `html select` like below

```
<select id="alias" name="alias">
  <option value="">-Select-</option>
  <option
          value='100'
          data-accountnumber='2251106207001'
          data-accountholder='Ashraful'
          data-mobilenumber='01811449003'
          data-email='shadiq2@yahoo.com'>
      testBeneficiary-1
  </option>
</select>
```

I need a `regular expression` for `JMeter` to extract the `value` which is `100` of above snippet. Can anyone help me with this? Thanks in advancet

Answer (score 1):

As per https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2897748

> You can't parse [X]HTML with regex. Because HTML can't be parsed by
>   regex. Regex is not a tool that can be used to correctly parse HTML.

I would suggest using [XPath Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Extractor) instead.

In your case XPath Extractor should be configured as follows:

- Check `Use Tidy` if data isn't XML/XHTML compliant, elsewise you'll get SAX Exception
- Reference Name: anything meaningful, it will be the name of JMeter Variable storing XPath Expression Result. Let it be `value`
- XPath Query:

  ```
  //select[@id='alias']/option[@data-email='shadiq2@yahoo.com']/@value
  ```

The XPath query above returns "value" attribute of option which "data-email" attribute is "shadiq2@yahoo.com" of select with "alias" id.

Once extracted you will be able to refer that variable as `${value}` or `${__V(value)}`

See [Using the XPath Extractor in JMeter](http://blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0) guide for more details, XPath language reference and short cookbook.

Comment: +1 to your answer. And shorter xpath would look like `//select[@id='alias']//option[2]//@value`

Comment: what if i need to extract the `value` of the `option` that has `innerHTML` "testBeneficiary-1"?

Comment: In that case XPath query would be `//select/option[contains(text(),'testBeneficiary-1')]/@value`

Answer (score 1):

The given html text

```
<select id="alias" name="alias">
  <option value="">-Select-</option>
  <option
          value='100'
          data-accountnumber='2251106207001'
          data-accountholder='Ashraful'
          data-mobilenumber='01811449003'
          data-email='shadiq2@yahoo.com'>
      testBeneficiary-1
  </option>
</select>
```

We can get the option value 100 using the following regex formats

Regex formats to get the value 100

```
<option value="">-Select-</option>\s\s\s<option\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\svalue='(.+)'
```

Note :

```
\s - means single space
\s\s\s - means three spaces
\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s - means eleven spaces
```